# Specify drop target for connected jquery-ui sortables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Given two sortables setup with the following:

```
<div class="task-list-wrapper">
    <ul class="task-list">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <button>Add task</button>
</div>

<div class="task-list-wrapper">
    <ul class="task-list">
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>six</li>
    </ul>
    <button>Add task</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('task-list').sortable({
    connect: 'task-list'
});
```

By default the drop-target when dragging items between lists is the `.task-list`. When the lists are empty however the drop target is really small. How can I specify `.task-list-wrapper` as the drop target? (I can't just make the `.task-list` element taller because the button sticks to the bottom of the list, which in the case of an empty list is at the top).

Working example: http://jsbin.com/hipetawemu/1/edit

Comment: The drop zone gets smaller because there is no content in the `.task-list`. Specify a `min-height` in CSS to match the default content height and it will retain its size when its empty.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that would cause the button to be pushed down the page, I want to allow users to drop into the area below the button.

Comment: Could you post a working example of the issue? It's a little difficult to visualise.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://jsbin.com/gelopikuho/1/edit?html,js,output so I want to able to drop an item in the area below the button, let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan starting with an empty list to make the problem a bit clearer, http://jsbin.com/hipetawemu/1/edit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well I seem to have cracked it, http://jsbin.com/fasotebete/1/edit?html,css,js,output - I actually tried this in my app but it didn't work, the real version is far more complicated so something must be throwing it off...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, so I've narrowed down the problem, http://jsbin.com/vuxehotace/1/edit?html,js,output - basically, it works unless the list you're dragging into starts empty.

Comment: Got there in the end - http://jsbin.com/vuxehotace/1/edit?html,css,js,output - I'm including a placeholder li in the list with display set to none. This ensures that the drop behaviour is always correct but doesn't actually upset the display.

Comment: That's right. An empty container has a height of 0px - so you can never possibly drop anything on it to raise the drop event. This is why it needs to have a `min-height`. You may be able to use one of the events on the parent to manually append the item to the child element though.

Comment: Ah, the placeholder solution is very elegant - glad you got it sorted.